# What issues can arise from calling contracts across different solidity versions?

Tags: version-pragma

What issues can arise from calling contracts across different solidity versions?

For my purposes, Contract A has been deployed with `pragma solidity 0.7.4;` and Contract B is deployed with `0.8.19`.

Do any of the changes mention in the [soliditylang release notes](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/080-breaking-changes.html) affect interactions with contracts on different versions?

Comment: Please accept the answer if it resolved your issue, or comment if you need any further help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interactions between contracts are external calls, so they will not share any resources. So this means that is perfectly safe to call contracts deployed using other versions of solidity.

The problem of mixing versions is when you mix versions on inherited contracts or contracts that are composed on the same deployment. Then you need to be extra careful or update older versions to newer to be able to use the same compiler and avoid bugs.

Answer (score 2):

Solidity is a high-level language and also a compiler.

Different versions of solidity only matter when you want to compile, for example, a smart contract written in solidity 0.7.4 with compiler version 0.8.19. It will fail.

The functions, variables, and mappings you write in your solidity code are essentially transformed into low-level [opcodes](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/evm/opcodes/) and stored on Ethereum. As long as the opcode don't change(it won't), there is nothing you need to worry about.

As prc mentioned, interactions between contracts are external calls, you don't need to worry about compatibility issues.

Hope this provides additional information to this question.